# How do I transpose two hashes in ruby to make a single hash or array?

Tags: ruby, hash, enumerable

I want to take the two hashes below and combine them into a new hash or array:

```
hash1 = {1=>"]", 2=>"}", 3=>")", 4=>"(", 5=>"{", 6=>"["}
hash2 = {1=>"[", 2=>"{", 3=>"(", 4=>")", 5=>"}", 6=>"]"}
```

I want the result to look something like this:

```
result = {"["=>"]", "{"=>"}", "("=>")"}
```

or

```
result = [ ["[","]"], ["{","}"], ["(",")"] ]
```

Is there a ruby method that can do this?

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Hash#transform_keys](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys):

```
res = hash1.transform_keys { |k| hash2[k] }

res #=> {"["=>"]", "{"=>"}", "("=>")", ")"=>"(", "}"=>"{", "]"=>"["}

res.first(3) #=> [["[", "]"], ["{", "}"], ["(", ")"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, another way you can get what you want is by using [Hash#deep_merge](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/deep_merge)
like so:

```
res = hash1.deep_merge(hash2) { |key, this_val, other_val| [other_val , this_val] }.values
# =>  [["[", "]"], ["{", "}"], ["(", ")"], [")", "("], ["}", "{"], ["]", "["]
res.first(3) 
# => [["[", "]"], ["{", "}"], ["(", ")"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
hash1.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), h| h[hash2[k]] = v }

#=> {"["=>"]", "{"=>"}", "("=>")", ")"=>"(", "}"=>"{", "]"=>"["}
```

Or:

```
hash2.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), h| h[v] = hash1[k] }

#=> {"["=>"]", "{"=>"}", "("=>")", ")"=>"(", "}"=>"{", "]"=>"["}
```

Comment: This has the advantage over @iGan's excellent answer in that it can be used with Ruby versions prior to 2.4, when `Hash#transform_keys` made its debut.

Answer (score 0):

```
hash1.merge(hash2){|_, v1, v2| [v1, v2]}.values
# => [["]", "["], ["}", "{"], [")", "("], ["(", ")"], ["{", "}"], ["[", "]"]]
```